# A loop for pairwise comparison with previous value within a column in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

One crucial step in my project is to track the absolute difference of values in a column of pandas dataframe for subsamples.

I managed to write a for-loop to create my subsamples. I select every person and go through every year this person is observed. I further accessed the index of each groups first element, and even compared it the each ones second element.

Here is my MWE data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2001', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009',
                             '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009',
                            '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009'],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
                          '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
                         '5', '5', '5','5', '5', '5', '5'],
                   'money': ['15', '15', '15', '21', '21', '21', '21', 
                             '17', '17', '17', '20', '17', '17', '17',
                            '25', '30', '22', '25', '8', '7', '12']}).astype(int)
```

Here is my code:

```py
# do it for all IDs in my dataframe
for i in df.id.unique():
# now check every given year for that particular ID
    for j in df[df['id']==i].year: 
# access the index of the first element of that ID, as integer
        index = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[0]
# use that index to calculate absolute difference of the first and second element 
        abs_diff = abs( df['money'].iloc[index] - df['money'].iloc[index+1] )
# print all the changes, before further calculations
        index =+1
        print(abs_diff)
```

My index is not updating. It yields 0000000 0000000 5555555 (3 x 7 changes) but it should show 0,0,0,6,0,0,0   0,0,0,3,-3,0,0   0,5,-8,3,-17,-1,5 (3 x 7 changes). Since the either first or last element have no change, I added 0 in front of each group.

**Solution** I changed the second loop from for to while:

```
for i in df.id.unique():
first = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[0] # ID1 = 0 
last = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[-1] # ID1 = 6

while first < last:

    abs_diff = abs( df['money'][first] - df['money'][first+1] ) 
    print(abs_diff)
    first +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently always checking the first value of each batch, so you'd need to do:

```
# do it for all IDs in my dataframe
for i in df.id.unique():
# now check every given year for that particular ID
    for idx,j in enumerate(df[df['id']==i].year): 
# access the index of the first element of that ID, as integer
        index = df[df['id']==i].index.values.astype(int)[idx]
# use that index to calculate absolute difference of the first and second element
        try:
            abs_diff = abs( df['money'][index] - df['money'][index+1] )
        except:
            continue
# print all the changes, before further calculations
        index =+1
        print(abs_diff)
```

Which outputs:

```
0
0
6
0
0
0
4
0
0
3
3
0
0
8
5
8
3
17
1
5
```

Comment: I tried to change one last thing about your solution, but am stuck again. In your output changes are calculated across all observations, and not within groups. You can see this in your output value "4" at index 7. There should be no change here, since ID starts again. Can you give me advice on this? I mean: Why does the second loop not stop at j? Regards

Answer (score 2):

`for i in df.id.unique():
    for j in df[df['id']==i].year:

```
    index = df[(df['id']==i)&(df['year']==j)].index.values[0].astype(int)
    try:
        abs_diff = abs(df['money'].iloc[index] - df['money'].iloc[index+1] )
    except:
        pass
    print(abs_diff)`
```

output:
0
0
6
0
0
0
4
0
0
3
3
0
0
8
5
8
3
17
1
5

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. Here's the same issue as with U9' answers. The second loop seems to not work. Since value "4" should not exist. Regards @tawab_shakeel

Comment: @MarcoDoe Exacty you are right .Thanks for explaining the issue